# How to sign in user using modal without devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for ways to sign up a user from anywhere in the site using a modal window without using Devise. All the resources i found refer to Devise which i guess its because its popular but what would be the equivalent of the Devise solution against a custom sign up using bcrypt.

in Devise you would need to setup these methods in a helper

```
helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

and have a `form_tag` to use that resource, what would be the equivalent code without Devise?

I know i could use a global `@user = User.new` instance variable, but is that a good thing to do?

Comment: I think writing an entire authentication system kind of goes beyond the scope of something to ask on stackoverflow. Seeing as you'll have to take into consideration things like password encryption, user session management, and the whole ui-flow on your own and you seem to be asking about instance variables instead, I think you might have some reading to do. I'm just going to point you here, it's a bit old, but will still tell you pretty much what you'd need to get going without devise: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast

Comment: @photoionized  i think you misunderstood or my post was misleading. I have a custom authentication system in place. What i need is the best way to implement an app-wide implementation of sign in/login modal that gets the job done similar to what Devise can do. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case just put something like a class method on user that's called something like `authenticate` or `login` which accepts user credentials and returns the user. Store the user's id in the current session and you should be good. On subsequent requests you can just do something like `User.find(session[:user])` to get the user again. To make things more DRY you can implement a `current_user` method on ApplicationController that does this.

Comment: And don't forget to memoize so you aren't hitting your database every call to `current_user`